# Как вывести статью один раз из любой категории на Django?

Tags: django

Нужно вывести определенное количество статей, но проблема в том, что некоторые статьи относятся к нескольким категориям через ManyToManyField.
Получается такой вывод:

```
{% for article_page in article_pages %}
    ...
    {% for article in article_page.categories.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'articles' article.slug article_page.slug %}">
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Таким образом выведется одна статья с ссылками из разных категорий, к которым она относится.
Вопрос, как вывести статью с одной ссылкой?
Может есть какой-то способ вывести или отфильтровать? Уже даже не знаю.
Надеюсь поможет кто, спасибо.

Модели

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...


class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент нашел такой способ выбрать первый элемент из списка ManyToManyField:

```
{% for article_page in article_pages %}
    ...
    {% for article_page.categories.all|first as article %}
        <a href="{% url 'articles' article.slug article_page.slug %}">
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Спасибо всем, кто помогал в решении вопроса. Если есть замечания по решению - пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, поменяйте all на first и выведется ссылка только на первую категорию.

Comment: Выдает ошибку object is not iterable.

Comment: В общем, Ваше предложение натолкнуло на один способ. Вот такой:
{% with article_page.categories.all|first as article %} ... {% endwith %}
Сработало! Если есть замечания по такому способу - пишите.
Спасибо,что навели на ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Можно тогда вообще от внутреннего цикла избавиться:

```
<a href="{% url 'articles' article_page.categories.first.slug article_page.slug %}">
```

Comment: Можно, спасибо)